# Object.values() doesn't derive type from a union or Records

Tags: typescript

When used with TypeScript, `Object.values()` fails to derive the correct type from a union of `Record`s:

```js
type A = Record<string, number>;
type B = Record<string, boolean>;

function func(value: A | B) {
    const properties = Object.values(value); // any[]
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwGdhMBLAOwHMAaKUgVwFsAjCTAPgG4AoUSKAIQTI0WPIRIVqjdOgA2EAIakOnTgDNapVMGLpSUdZoAUAN3kzaEAFywoAH34BKKAG9OUd1AylCUMJnSQmNoQ+IIA8owAVmjAAHSm5iEmZhYO7FAA9BlQiiAA2gC6nAC+QA)

I expect `properties` to be of type `number[] | boolean[]`, but the actual type is `any[]`.

Is there a way to derive the correct type from `Object.values()`?

Comment: You can widen `A | B` to something easier for the compiler to accept, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1kOYm). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @jcalz. Looking at the playground you provided, I'm not sure how it is better than `const properties: (number | boolean)[] = Object.values(value);` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwGdhMBLAOwHMAaKUgVwFsAjCTAPgG4AoUSKAIQTI0WPIRIVqjdOgA2EAIakOnTgDNapVMGLpSUdZoAUAN3kzaEAFywoAH34BKKAG9OUd1AylCUMJnSQmNoQ+NaGdEwsdlBSsgqkDgDaALqCAPKMAFZowAB0puYhJmYWDlwAvkA)) since you explicitly use `number | boolean`.
Anyway, it doesn't meet my needs. In the code, we are not sure what `A` and `B` are. We only know they are Records.

Comment: Because your way [doesn't catch errors](https://tsplay.dev/WJpOlN) since it passes through `any` and will allow anything.  How would you like to proceed now?  EDIT: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates you only knowing that they are Records.  Is it generic or something?

Comment: I see how it's better now, thank you. I will try to come up with a more illustrative use case.
Also, can you explain why `Object.values()` behaves like this and returns `any[]`?

Comment: If I write an answer I would be happy to explain why it behaved that way.  Comments aren't a great place for that, other than possibly brief summaries, like "TS doesn't like to synthesize unions from multiple inference candidates so it failed, and `Object.values()` has two overloads so it resolved to the second more general overload returning `any`".

Comment: Here is the best I can describe the use case I'm facing: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbaV8N). Bottom line, we have an eslint rule that complains about using `any` in template literal expressions.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to put your [mre] in there, or else we risk it disappearing.  I don't understand why you are using `A | B` this way instead of `Record<string, T1 | T2>`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3E1bw).  The latter will accept a value of type `A | B`. Could you demonstrate some code (in the question) that motivates what you're doing, why it has to be a union-of-records, and why you have to "derive" the type from the union instead of just rewriting the type yourself?

Comment: I can't use `Record<string, T1 | T2>` because it's not something I control. I know it would solve my problem. I can't rewrite the type myself because in reality the type is more complex, and it would be hard to maintain. I'm new to TypeScript, you can see it in my poor wording. I hoped to find an elegant solution to making `Object.values` "derive" a type from a union of Records, but it seems to me it can't be achieved without knowing the exact types of object values.

Comment: Okay, does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wv1XAm) meet your needs?  You can query the type system for the appropriate union and then specify it when calling `Object.values`.  If that works I'll write up an answer explaining, if not, uh... ‍♂️

Comment: Looks like `typeof value[string]` is what I was missing.

Comment: Okay I’ll write an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`Object.values(v)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) the compiler tries to match `v` with `{[k: string]: T}` for a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `T` that it infers (according to [this call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2170e6c6cc12f08bfa2975955da2f145e4be6101/src/lib/es2017.object.d.ts#L6)).

So if `v` is of a type like `{[k: string]: Z}`, then the compiler will infer `T` as `Z`, and everything will succeed.  But if `v`'s type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of records like `{[k: string]: X} | {[k: string]: Y}`, things are different.  One might hope that `T` could be inferred as the union `X | Y`.  But the inference algorithm does not work that way.  The type `X | Y` does not appear anywhere directly in the input type, and the compiler will not *synthesize* union types from multiple inference candidates.  Instead the compiler picks one candidate ... let's say, `X` ... and then issues an error if `Record<string, X> | Record<string, Y>` is not assignable to `Record<string, X>`.

This refusal to synthesize union types is intentional; often people would rather see an error than have the compiler start creating unions to make things succeed, especially because in many cases that would make just about every call succeed, even ones doing crazy things like `compare(3, "oops")`, assuming `compare` is of a type like `<T>(a: T, b: T) => number`.  People *want* to see that fail instead of having `T` be inferred as `number | string`.

In your case though you *want* that union to be inferred. There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) to have a way to say that such an inference should happen. But it's not part of the language yet, and even if it were, the `Object.values()` call signature might not be changed to use it.

So we can't rely on the compiler to infer the union type you want directly.

---

Instead, we can *specify* the union type when we call `Object.values()`.  That would look like `Object.values<X | Y>(v)`.  In your example, then you could just write `Object.values<number | boolean>(value)`, and you're done.

But you don't want to hard code that type argument that way.  You'd like it to depend on `value` such that if its type changes to some other union of records, things would continue to work.  So that means: given a value `value` of a type like `{[k: string]: X} | {[k: string]: Y}`, how can we *compute* the type `X | Y`?

Here we can use [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) on `value` to get the type of value, and then we can [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type with `string` to get the type of the properties of `value` at a `string` key.

That is:

**`Object.values<typeof value[string]>(value); // okay`**

Or, to see the general example:

```
function foo<X, Y>() {
    type A = Record<string, X>;
    type B = Record<string, Y>;
    function func(value: A | B) {
        return Object.values<typeof value[string]>(value);        
    }
    // func(value: Record<string, X> | Record<string, Y>): (X | Y)[]
}
```

Inside `foo()`, the `func()` function accepts a value of type `A | B`, and returns a value of type `(X | Y)[]`, without us having to hardcode the type `X | Y` ourselves.  Instead, `typeof value[string]` evaluates to `X | Y` and we use that.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKCpqw4C4oB2ArgLYBGEATgNwZYDGA9gCYT4DOwlAlgQOa0AvmlCRYAJiSo6mYOPzFyVWlihNWHLrwFphI8NACCUgEoQmlZgB5OPfgBpYcAHy1R0AEKnzjSza0OEq5oaABmRAT0wNyMBFDhkQAUAG4AhgA2RGxQxgA+UB4AlNKqlBDARJRxAPJkAFbmwAB0aZkQ7FbujKFQrVkA2rbaALrOKRlZhU0kqWCJ3MAQJEjOJaoMsZxqLNDIC0tN6hAq65hlFVVQAAYAJChHglcnmIKFQiFhEVExcaGMjFYABqOACaY2K6FU7hy3gs1iGgUBwShBgKsN88ICfFByKwCW+sXiX3GbXweQKEJk63OlRq9UaLQm7U6Bm6vSZgyxoxJk2op0wVOEqgA9MKiUk+tkzHD-HZsVAkVB8tKMbLtDjCvhEoClVAQYV+sNdEA)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can define the interface for a patched object construct named `ObjectConstructorAlt`.

```
declare interface ObjectConstructorAlt {
    values<T>(o: T):
    T extends any ?
        T extends Record<string|number, infer V> ? V[] 
            : T extends (infer V)[] ? V[]
            : any
        : never       
    ;
}
type A = Record<string, number>;
type B = Record<string, boolean>;
declare const a:A;
declare const b:B;
declare const ab:A|B;

Object.values(a); // number[]
Object.values(b); // boolean[]
Object.values(ab); // any[]

// actual implementation
const ObjectAlt: ObjectConstructorAlt = {
    values<T>(x: T){ 
        return Object.values(x as object) as any; 
    }
}
ObjectAlt.values(a); // number[]
ObjectAlt.values(b); // boolean[]
ObjectAlt.values(ab); // number[] | boolean[]
```

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=28&ssc=46&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCDyARgFbioDCA9sgM6owCuYqFMAghKvAN4BQ8-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)

If you could persuade the TypeScript maintainers to swap the current `ObjectConstructor`

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];
    values(o: {}): any[];
    ...
}
```

for something like `ObjectConstructorAlt` then a patch on your end wouldn't be necessary.  That's unlikely though, as it could increase compile time and result in other things breaking.

**update** - FWIW I submitted this as [an issue to TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55116#issuecomment-1648444729) and the present behavior of `Object.values/entries` is determined to be **not a defect**.  There is a lot of history behind that decision which is [worth reading](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38520).

Comment: @Serhii Holinei - This answer will not change.

Comment: Thank you! You got my upvote. A separate thank you for filing the issue on GitHub and posting the feedback here. Much appreciated! However a simple `Object.values<typeof value[string]>(...)` is what I was looking for, based on the comment from @jcalz